# Negations before quantifiers in derivations of predicate logic

Tags: logic

Hi I would really appreciate your help in how to derive the following: the negation of the existential quantifier applied to a predicate is equivalent to the universal quantifier applied to the negation of the predicate.

Truly thankful,

PMi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one direction :

1) **∀x¬Px**

2) **∃xPx** --- assumed [a]

3) **Pa** --- assumed [b] from 2) for **∃**-elim

4) **¬Pa** --- from 1)

5) **contradiction** --- closing **∃**-elim and discharging [b]

> 6) **¬∃xPx** --- from 2) and 5) discharging [a].

Thus :

> > **∀x¬Px → ¬∃xPx** --- from 1) and 6) by **→**-intro.

---

For the other direction, we need *Double Negation* :

1) **¬∃xPx**

2) **¬∀x¬Px** --- assumed [a]

3) **Px** --- assumed [b]

4) **∃xPx** --- from 3) by **∃**-intro

5) **contradiction**

6) **¬Px** --- from 3) and 5), discharging [b]

7) **∀x¬Px** --- from 6) by **∀**-intro

8) **contradiction**

> 9) **∀x¬Px** --- from 2) and 8) by *Double Negation*, discharging [a]
>
> > **¬∃xPx → ∀x¬Px** --- from 1) and 9) by **→**-intro.

Comment: Thank you very much @MauroALLEGRANZA but what I am struggling with is with the tilda PRECEDING the quantifier and how to create substitutions for it. So this direction I got it down already, it is the other one that I find problematic. I would really appreciate your help :)

Comment: Yes, I am not looking for an explicit answer and I understand the general outline. However, how do I create a substitution instance for the assumption since the main connective is the tilda and not the universal quantifier? Without a substitution instance I cannot work since both in the premise and in the assumption I find the problem of the tilda being the main connective

Comment: Thank you very much @MauroALLEGRANZA, it has help me understand better the meaning behind each quantifier